# How to attach two fields in json response array in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, concatenation

I need to attach the `start_date` and `start_time` into one field in the response as `start` = `start_date` + `start_time` in the json array, this is how i get display the json array

[image]

I need to show as `start` : "2021-02-18 12:32:00" with all the other fields too

Here's my controller function

```
public function calendar(Job $job)
{

    $user = auth()->user();
    $calendar= $job->where('user_id',$user->id)->get();

    return response()->json($calendar);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [map()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map) function to loop over and can add new key like this

```php
public function calendar(Job $job)
{

    $user = auth()->user();
    $calendar = $job->where('user_id', $user->id)->get();

    $calendar->map(function($row){  
        return $row->start = $row->start_date . ' ' . $row->start_time;
    });

    return response()->json($calendar);
}
```

Comment: This didn't work ;(  i got the same response json array as before without any errors

Comment: Now the response attaches the `start_date` and `end_date` this is how it shows `[
"2021-02-18 12:32:00",
"2021-02-18 07:32:00",
"2021-03-01 11:44:00"
]` but i need to show as `start `: "2021-02-18 12:32:00"  with all the other fields

Comment: still i get the same `[
"2021-02-18 12:32:00",
"2021-02-18 07:32:00",
"2021-03-01 11:44:00"
]` 
;(

Comment: @Jareer i have tested this and it works as expected may be your doing somthing wrong

Comment: Yes the codes work without any issues but i dont get the expected result,

Comment: @Jareer what laravel version your using?

Comment: but if i dump `$row->start = $row->start_date . ' ' . $row->start_time` i get the start date & start time fields attached as `"2021-02-18 12:32:00"`

Comment: Sorry @Kamlesh it your codes worked, the issue was in the model I had to add  
`protected $visible  = ['start'];` in the `Job` model and it worked, Thanks a lot man !

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the above problem finally by adding the below codes

Controller function

```
public function calendar(Job $job)
{
$user = auth()->user();

$calendar = $job->where('user_id',$user->id)->get();

$calendar = $calendar->map(function ($post) {
    $post['start'] =  $post->start_date . ' ' . $post->start_time;
    $post['end'] =  $post->end_date . ' ' . $post->end_time;
    // unset($post['name']);
    return $post;
});

return response()->json($calendar);
}
```

Model

```
protected $visible  = ['start','end'];
```

Result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your Job model you can use the `$append` and create and attribute for it then it will always be part of the results with the model:

```
class Job extends Model

    ...

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'start',
    ];

    ...

    public function getStartAttribute()
    {
        return $this->start_date . $this->start_time;
    }

    ...
```